# Complex bash pipeline works in jumps

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, statusbar, xargs

My intention is to output log of recursive `wget` in one line, 'status bar'-like. So I assembled this pipeline (my `wget` call has a bit more options but I left those only essential for the problem described) :

```
wget -r -nv ftp://example.com 2>&1 | cut -c1-80 | xargs -I line echo -ne 'line\033[0K\r'
```

Let me explain what I meant to do. Maybe there's something wrong with my command.

- `-r` means 'recursive download';
- `-nv` makes messages about each downloads to be brief, like: "time: URL -> local file";
- `&2>1` redirects stderr to stdout so I could work with the messages through pipes;
- `| cut -c1-80` cuts the output line to 80 characters. Sometimes the URL and local file name together make a long string which breaks a line into 2 or more. And I need it to fit in a single line of console. 80 stands here just for example. In my script I determine console width with `tput cols`;
- `| xargs -I line echo -ne 'line\033[0K\r'` prints output of previous command and adds two special characters: `\033[OK` - end of line, which cleans the rest of line if there are any characters left from prevoius output; and `\r` - carriage return which sets the cursor to the beginning of current line.

So the wanted behaviour is:

1. `wget` downloads a file and tries to print a notice about this to stdout
2. `cut` **immediately** intercepts the output of wget and trims it to 80 chars
3. `xargs` catches the trimmed line and prints it **immediately** with special characters

So I should see some kind of status bar where current download is displayed.

**But!** All I see is nothing happening for 10 to 60 seconds and then all messages about downloads that was done during that time are printed in about 1 second. They actually printed the way I wanted, but very fast. Then again, a pause, another portion of messages in 1 second, and so on. So all is fine except the **immediately**-ness.

When I remove `xargs` part, the messages are displayed instantly (but not in one line). When I remove `cut` call, they are instant, but sometimes the line breaks with some really long URL. If I remove only special characters from `echo` call the output is still "jumpy" and not in one line.

To reproduce this, you can replace "ftp://example.com" with any URL (HTTP will work too) that can be used for testing recursive download, i.e. in case of FTP has many files and directories and in case of HTTP has many links to pages that have more links (don't be afraid that it might try to download all Internet, beacuse `-r` option has default recursion level of 5). If you can't reproduce this, then I suppose it's something wrong with my distribution, please write about it in comments section below.

P.S. If you know a better way of organizing a status bar for `wget`, your comments are very welcome. But I am learning Bash and would like to know what is causing such strange behaviour. Maybe there's something about pipes or `echo` or `xargs` I don't know. So the question is why this pipeline work so and not as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is output buffering, there are solutions for this: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Unfortunately when I try to apply them, I get `xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`.

You have to try a different approach, I don't think `xargs` is a good choice for this task, try awk, perl, python, ruby...

Comment: Thanks! Now I know what was causing the problem (the buffering) and how to bypass it (awk). And yes, xargs really doesn't fit for strings manipulation.

Comment: So as a result my pipeline now is like: `wget -r -nv http://example.com 2>&1 | awk -W interactive '{ORS=""; print substr($0,1,80) "\033[0K\r" }'`. `-W interactive` makes awks do not buffer output and `ORS=""` gives us `print`'s without newlines.

Answer (score 2):

xargs gathers many lines of input and calls the command (echo in your situation) only once*. Add '-L 1' to the arguments to xargs and see if this helps.

* xargs uses more calls to the command if the commandline would grow too long, but groups as much as possible.

Comment: Seems reasonable and I didn't know that about xargs, but: 1) it doesn't help, did you try it and it worked?; 2) if I remove `| cut` pipe, it works as expected, without gathering lines.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the hint about `-L` option. I learned that it is somewhat incopatible with `-I`. That's what man-page says.